# Google Map background image is not showing properly in browser

Tags: javascript, css, google-maps

I am implementing a Google Map on my webpage using JavaScript. Here my problem is map is coming with `marker` but it's background image is not showing at all. The screen shot is given below.

[image]

Here is my code:

```
<div id="dvMap" style="width:1000px; height:1000px;"></div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>



<script>
    var markers = [{"lat":"20.295728","lng":"85.844990"},{"title":"shilparamam","lat":"20.295728","lng":"85.844990","description":"Mumbai formerly Bombay, is the capital city of the Indian state of Maharashtra."}];
    window.onload = function () {
    var mapOptions = {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(markers[0].lat, markers[0].lng),
    zoom: 10,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("dvMap"), mapOptions);
    var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
    var lat_lng = new Array();
    var latlngbounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
    for (i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
    var data = markers[i]
    var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(data.lat, data.lng);
    lat_lng.push(myLatlng);
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: myLatlng,
    map: map,
    title: data.title
    });
    latlngbounds.extend(marker.position);
    (function (marker, data) {
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function (e) {
    infoWindow.setContent(data.description);
    infoWindow.open(map, marker);
    });
    })(marker, data);
    }
    map.setCenter(latlngbounds.getCenter());
    map.fitBounds(latlngbounds);
    }
    </script>
```

Here I need the clear background image for the Google Map.

Comment: The posted code works for me. ([fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/w8nbhuos/)).  Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the issue.

Comment: @geocodezip : Yes, I posted required part of from my whole code. Individually its working fine i can not know why its not working in my project.

Comment: It is hard to help without a [mcve] that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: @geocodezip : Yes,thats also true. But here also only roadmap is showing instead of little bit details.

Comment: @geocodezip : Here also when i am clicking on satelite option this `Sorry we have no imagery here` message is coming.

Comment: Is your data valid?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127686/discussion-between-satya-and-geocodezip).

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use a simple iframe instead of such a long script? Below link provides you with simple steps to get an iframe code which you just need to embedd in your project or website using html div.
http://www.dummies.com/web-design-development/site-development/how-to-embed-a-google-map-with-iframe/

Comment: Click on this link [link](https://www.google.co.in/maps/@12.9539974,77.6309395,11z?hl=en) and enter you address in the search box.Press enter . You wil now get a google map for your address. Click on the share option in the left and select the 2nd tab **Embed Map** , then copy the iframe link they provide and embed in your html div of your project. For example , you will get something like this : <iframe src="some example" width="600" height="450" frameborder="0" style="border:0" allowfullscreen></iframe>

Comment: Here i dont need map for any particular location. I need the location on map as per `latitude and longitide` value which may assign dynamically.